# Is there a way to program C# windows apps on an Android Tablet?

Tags: c#, android, windows, compiler-construction

I am going away for the holidays but my windows laptop is broken, so all I have available to me is my android tablet.

I was wondering if there is any way I can continue to program my C# application, using my android tablet.

Internet connectivity would be limited to my phone, so it would be a preference to not use something like VNC.

I would like the ability to compile the C# code, using my android tablet. I have my doubts this is possible, as it would require some kind of windows emulator to run a windows program on my android device.

The device is a Nook HD+ or a Google Nexus 10, which I believe can't be rooted to run windows.
I have to leave pretty soon, so unless I can pick something up at Walmart or BestBuy for a fair price, it looks like I won't be able to do this :\

Comment: This is hardly "off-topic" asking for "favorite resources" or "recommend a tool." This is extremely specific, and quite a good question for those serious about programming at every opportunity. Not only are those who voted to close idiots, but those who downvoted ruin the potential of this site to serve users who use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to use an online compiler and editor, you can google to see a list of them.  This should work fine tethered to a 3G phone as it's not bandwidth intensive.

Comment: Voting this as best answer, as it's the only answer and the question will probably be closed soon due to the idiotic high rep users who seem to want to do more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no C# compiler on Android. You can edit you source code, but to actually compile you need to have a computer.

I suggest you buy a computer, borrow, or fix one (if you're programming, you should be able to fix them right?)

Many computer science types (or computer related degrees) will have multiple computers. I have at least 3 working laptops laying around.

Comment: Odd answer. The number of computers you have is more of an indication of income than field of study. Even so, not everyone is into laptops. I find laptops to be inferior PoS compared to a desktop. For mobile purposes, I need only my tablet. While I do own 3 active computers, computer parts, 4 broken laptops, and multiple tablets/phones, this is because I have disposable income more than it is because I am a huge tech nerd.

Comment: Deserving of its own comment, is the confusion between programming software and building hardware. Knowing how to program is no indication of knowing how to build computers or fix hardware. While I do know how to do both, they are entirely separate skills. I know amazing programmers who barely know anything about hardware, and there are endless numbers of people who can build computers- very few of those can program, let alone competently. Finally, fixing computers, especially laptops, requires buying parts. Walmart does not sell tiny cables to reconnect netbooks with screens.

Comment: The answer is the hard truth. People who build software and have no idea how the computer works are like a race car driver that doesn't know how cars work. Fixing a computer is much like debugging a program. You have symptoms, you isolate the problem, you Google suggestions, and then you fix or replace the problem. And if you work with computers regularly, you do build up several spare computers, whether they're from friends that no longer need them or you've replaced your old equipment.

Comment: The answer isn't a "hard truth". The answer is misinforming anyone who reads this to what is absolutely NOT true. There is no need to understand how to build hardware when all you're doing is creating software. Unless that software works directly with that hardware. Even those who understand who hardware functions, such as the limitations of the graphics card, does not in ANY way need to understand how to install that graphics card in a PC. You still fail to grasp the simple fact that hardware/software are two different things, and accruing "spare parts" is not a sign of programming...

Comment: Please ignore the mindset of people like msm8bball. There are a lot online who believe one has to know EVERYTHING about something to be skilled at programming. You don't have to understand hardware to program software, just the same as you don't have to be able to read binary code to program in C++. You don't have to know assembly to render an image to a screen.

Comment: Resist this type of philosophy that ignores the fact that one doesn't need to know unrelated subjects to fully understand related subjects. There is a reason software programmers get payed more than people who build PC's for resale. And that reason is NOT because programmers know how to build PC's for resale.